# Click a specific link in Firefox browser using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, click

I am new to coding and just started learning VB.net (because of background of VB6)

Now I am writing a simple program in VB.net which

1. Opens google.com in Firefox browser.
2. Searches for some query e.g. "ABC"
3. Clicks on a perticular link (e.g. abc.com) in search results.

Now I have done part 1 and part 2 but I cant find a way to get a particlular link clicked.

This is what I have tried uptil now

```
Button1.Click
    Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", "https://www.google.com/")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000) 
    SendKeys.SendWait("ABC")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500) 
    SendKeys.SendWait("~")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

Now how do I programmatically click on a particular href (e.g. abc.com).

For some constraint I cannot use Webbrowser component for this program.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the purpose of that program? There might be better ways in .NET doing what you're trying to do via a browser and SendKeys.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been diving down this rabbit hole myself. I would suggest checking out :https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/. There looks to be documentation for VB that could help. My application is written in C# so don't know if what I have written would have much crossover.

```
// This is example c# code for using selenium. 
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  string url = "webpage.com";
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
  Console.ReadLine();
  driver.Quit();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The main problem I suppose with Selenium will arise when in due course I have to change user agents of browser (chrome driver, gecko etc). From web I came to know that changing user agents will prove very tedious with selenium and the same problem is with WebBrowser component that comes with VB.net. Changing user agent repeatedly is very tedious task.

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand fully, are you wanting to pass a result found in a Firefox browser to a chrome browser? (sorry my original code example was mistakenly written for chrome).

Comment: I want to search a query in google using Firefox browser and subsequently click on a link in the search results. Your code will navigate to a URL, I suppose, but how do I click a particular link on that page

Comment: Ah okay yes, the code example above will get you to google (or what ever web page you put in for the url variable.). Entering a search into google should be straight forward, it is just a matter of having the program find the search text box and entering in the search string, and clicking the search box. Or you can directly search with :https://www.google.com/search?q=abc. Picking the result you are wanting is the part I am unsure of, but the results should follow a structure when you inspect the page, its just a matter of finding the right path.